# winError 32 permission error on deleting file with scrapy

Tags: python, file, scrapy

I have a scrapy python scraper. At this project, I always used `with` statement for file handling, just like this:

```
with open('file2.json', 'r', encoding="utf8") as file_data:
    datas = json.load(file_data)
```

But when i want to close this file, I get this error:

```
PermissionError: [WinError 32] The process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process: 'file2.json'
```

The code that supposed to delete this file is :

```
filename = 'file2.json'
    if os.path.exists(filename):
        os.remove(filename)
```

I tried some methods to solve this but it didn't help, the first was this code before deleting:

```
os.chmod(filename, 0o777)
```

The second was opening and closing file before deleting it:

```
fn = open(filename, 'r')
fn.close()
```

None of this ways work and I'm still getting permission error for deleting this file. Is there a way to close all open files in Python garbage collector? How can I solve this issue ?

Answer (score 1):

I know this post is old, but there may be other people with this problem. This is how I managed to deal with it.

This problem of the scraper having the file handler opened after finishing, in my case, happens when my spider doesn't yield values or I try to close the spider through a `CloseSpider` exception.

So, what I did was, instead of interrupting the spider or avoiding it from yielding values, was to yield a single trash value which I could track later:

```
class Scraper(scrapy.Spider):
    # your spider's attributes (name, domains, start urls, etc)
    scrape = True
    trashYielded = False

    def parse(self, response):
        for href in response.css('my selector'):
            if href == 'http://foo.bar':
                self.scrape = False
            if self.scrape:
                # Here you yield your values as you would normally
                yield {'url': href}
            else:
                if not self.trashYielded:
                    yield {'trashKey': 'trashValue'}
                    self.trashYielded = True
```

I know this is a mess and there must be better ways for doing this, but no one has provided one (at least I wasn't able to find any after hours).

The `scrape` variable tells if your spider must keep scraping or not, and the `trashYielded` tells if you have thrown the trash value (this way, we only throw one trash value).

In my example, I want to stop my scraping when I find a link to certain page, and when I find it I set the `scrape` variable to `False` (meaning I don't want to continue scraping).

Next, I'll only yield values if `scrape = True`, otherwise check if the spider has thrown a trash value (and do it if it hasn't).

When you process your data, you should just check if there is a 'trashKey' between your data and just drop it.

Hope this helps anyone (or attracts someone who could bring a better way) ^^